# How to check defined variable with external method / function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a code like this:

```
function checkDefined(v: any): boolean { // external function
    return v !== undefined
}

function mult(m?: number): number {
    if (checkDefined(m)) 
        return m * 3; // <<< Object is possibly 'undefined'.

    if (m !== undefined) 
        return m * 3; // OK

    throw new Error('"m" is not defined"')    
}
```

How to check with external function if 'm' is defined?

[Sandbox here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgUwgawCJuDMNAEwAoA3ALkQEMwBPASioCM44AbNWxAbwChEgxACc0UEMKRlEAQgC8cxOCJ4CxPgF8+fUJFgJEAWxDsoJQwH4qYEIeZphTRDbsPeAoTGCISqDDlVCUkMGBkQPISFRcUkjRAAqRABmAG4I8MivH0NZBSUwFXwgsPTI6IkkHMTU9PSoFGE4AHdnNBaAUWFG4RIAcgAiQ37EGABnZzgoREK1In7esKFNIA)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) (expression that performs a runtime check that guarantees the type in some scope):

```
function checkDefined<T>(v: T | undefined): v is T {
    return v !== undefined
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgUwgawCJuDMNAEwB4AVAPgAoA3ALkTMQB9Fwi8DiBKBmxGAGdGiAN4AoRFMQAnNFBAyk-AIQBeNWzAd8hIuIC%2048aEiwEiALYgANlCqWA-AzAhLAIzQzeiVx69iktIwwIhUqBg4nHoO3NxB0tJyCkpWiABUiADMANzGiSFhlojqmuzRPAmJsvKKSMWZufnSUCgycADuvmhdAKIy7TJUAOQARJajAsJgcFCIOlxEo8PxBkA)